# Apache2 libapreq2 on OpenSUSE 11.1

Tags: apache2, opensuse

I'm trying to install software based on Apache2/mod_perl2/Perl onto an OpenSUSE 11.1 box.

libapreq2 doesn't seem to be anywhere in the OpenSUSE repository, and CPAN won't install it because my mod_perl is from the package manager, not from source.

I'd really rather stick with packages for this install, rather than building from source tarballs, because I'd like package upgrades & security patches to work.

Anyone got any idea what I'm missing?

*PS: Yes, I know it "just works" with Debian/Ubuntu distros :-).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sigh* ... seconds after I asked, I stumbled across

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Apache:/Modules/Apache_openSUSE_11.1/repodata/
```

and it finally occured to me to

```
zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Apache:/Modules/Apache_openSUSE_11.1
zypper in zypper in libapreq2 libapreq2-devel perl-Apache2-Request apache2-mod_apreq2 apache2-mod_apreq2-devel
```

which has at least got me some of the way ... the remaining problem is described at [WebGUI, and SuSE, Apache - oh my.](http://computergod.typepad.com/home/2007/06/webgui_and_suse.html) & I've worked around it with a /etc/apache2/http.conf.local file.

Answer (score 1):

In the future use software search: http://software.opensuse.org/search

E.g.: http://software.opensuse.org/search?baseproject=openSUSE%3A11.1&p=1&q=libapreq2

Comment: Thanks ... turns out I was getting confused between libapreq (in the default repo) and libapreq2 (only in external repo)